# Layered SKTileMapNodes

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, sktilemapnode

I am trying to make a Dungeons and Dragons app that has different editable layers of objects. The lowest layer should be the background, such as water, roads, etc. The second layer should be terrain objects such as trees and buildings. The third layer should be placeable objects such as players, monsters, NPCs, and chests.

I have been trying to use two separate SKTileMapNodes, setting one zPosition above the other, then placing SKShapeNodes on top for placeable objects. However, I cannot seem to get two SKTileMapNodes working simultaneously.

Here are my two SKTileMapNodes. I cannot use the editor to get any tiles to display in ObjectMap. The BackgroundMap is all of the coloration currently. I want to put a blank grid of tiles like such in the ObjectMap:
Blank tile

[image]

TileMapNodes (used imgur because of an error):

[image]

Is there a better way to accomplish my goals? I would like to use the SKTileMap as it is easy to change/ paint over.

Comment: Is there a reason to have the camera as a child of the ObjectMap? You could try making the camera a child of the Scene.

Comment: Yeah i was just testing something.

Comment: have your very bottom-most tile map layer as the main tile map layer then add all the other tile map layers as children of your main tile map layer in the order you want to layer them (thats how i do it